# self.init() causes convenience init(){ } to run infinitely

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, core-bluetooth

I have a class which I am trying to initiate, however, as the title suggests, the `convenience init` method runs infinitely. Why is this?

```
class Peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate
{
    var peripheralManager : CBPeripheralManager!
    convenience init(delegate: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate?, queue: DispatchQueue?)
    {
        print("howdy")
        self.init()
        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBPeripheralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])
        peripheralManager.add(myCBService)
    }
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager)
    {
    }
}

let myPeripheral = Peripheral.init()
```

I ran my program for about ten seconds, and "howdy" printed 42,266 times. I put the print statement BELOW self.init(), and "howdy" did not print at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have found a little conflict between the Objective-C and Swift implementation.

`CBPeripheralManager`  has 3 `init` methods which basically work like this:

```
convenience init() {
    self.init(delegate: nil, queue: nil)
}

convenience init(delegate: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate?, queue: DispatchQueue?) {
    self.init(delegate: delegate, queue: queue, options: nil)  
}

// designated
init(delegate: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate?, queue: DispatchQueue?, options: [String : Any]?)
   // the actual implementation
}
```

Once you have declared a new `convenience` initializer, the two convenience initializers get removed and only the one defined by you exists. Normally, you wouldn't be able to call `Peripheral.init()` at all. However, the problem is that Objective-C classes *always* have an `init` method without parameters.

That means that `init()` delegates to your new convenience initializer and your initializer delegates to `init()` again, ending up in an infinite loop.

Solution, don't call `init()`. Call the designated initializer:

```
class Peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    var peripheralManager : CBPeripheralManager!

    convenience init(delegate: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate?, queue: DispatchQueue?) {
        print("howdy")
        self.init(delegate: delegate, queue: queue, options: nil)
        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBPeripheralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])
        peripheralManager.add(myCBService)
    }
}
```

However, there seems to be a deeper problem. Why do you create a new `CBPeripheralManager` from inside a `CBPeripheralManager`?

Isn't what you want actually the following?:

```
class Peripheral: NSObject, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager!
    override init() {
        print("howdy")

        super.init()

        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBPeripheralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])
        peripheralManager.add(myCBService)
    }

    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Sulthan . Your thorough answer cleared up a lot of confusion for me, however I followed the instructions and it tells me that I can't reference self before a super.init() call. How can I work around this, and also why is calling super.init() necessary for referencing self?

Comment: @Nathan Oh sorry, I missed that `self` reference. Using a `var` is probably a better idea then. Or a `lazy var`. The problematic part is that you cannot use `self` until the whole object is constructed (after initialization). And you have to initialize local variables before calling `super.init`. There are workarounds but some of them are not good for every situation.